# Corpus reading from pdf OR text in R

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I have a large list of files I want to read in R as a Corpus. All of the files were pdf, but recently, I realize some of them will be txt.

Before I had the text files, I was simply creating a list of pdf files that are in the directory and reading them using the Corpus function with readerControl:

```
getwd()
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
corp <- Corpus(URISource(files),
               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
```

I´ve tried to create a combined list of pdfs and txts, but I can´t find a way to use the readerContrl for pdf or txt:

```
files1 <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
files2 <- list.files(pattern = "txt$")
files<-c(files1,files2)

corp <- Corpus(URISource(files),
               readerControl = list(reader = c(readPDF,readPlain)))
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
I thought about merging two Copuses elements, one that reader=readPDF, another that reader=readPlain. But since I am new to text mining, I am not sure what is the best practice to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the easier way using the **readtext** package.  If your mix of .txt and .pdf files are in the same subdirectory, call this `path_to_your_files/`, then you can read them all in and then make them into a **tm** Corpus using `readtext()`.  This function automagically recognises different input file types and converts them into UTF-8 text for text analysis in R.  (The `rtext` object created here is a special type of data.frame that includes a document identifier column and a column called `text` that contains the converted text contents of your input documents.)

```
rtext <- readtext::readtext("path_to_your_files/*")
tm::Corpus(VectorSource(rtext[["text"]]))
```

**readtext** objects can also be used directly with the [**quanteda** package](https://quanteda.io) as inputs to `quanteda::corpus()` if you wanted to try an alternative to **tm**.

Comment: This is great, Ken! More general than my first approach. Also, I will study the readtext also: thank you for the tip!